# How to use ui-view on RenderBody() in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have this mark-up html with the @RenderBody():

```
<div layout="column" class="relative" layout-fill role="main">
    <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings" ng-disabled="true">
                    <md-icon md-svg-icon="navigation:menu"></md-icon>
            </md-button>

            <md-button ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</md-button> 
            <md-button ui-sref="home">Home</md-button> 
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-fill md-padding>
        <div id="main-content" ui-view="">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

and the js here:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home/Index');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/Home/Index',
        templateUrl: '/Home/Index' // corresponds to an MVC partial route
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: 'Home/Dashboard',
        templateUrl: '/Home/Dashboard' // corresponds to an MVC partial route
    })
});
```

The result is its own view inside a view. I cant figure it out.
Here is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but, this helped me to solve this problem.
Basically, I had kind of same code, I combined the Ravi Kiran answer with this:

I putted this on the top of my 'Index.cshtml' and in my case was 'Main.cshtml' as well (doesn't worked):

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
```

But I added this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

And my 'Layout.cshtml' has this:

```
<div ui-view="mainView">
        @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem in few of my apps.
Your layout is loading twice.
All you need to do is "make your layout null" while rendering from uiroute as below.
Add this on top of your Index.cshtml page

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
```

Or load ui-view out side the content div

```
 <md-content layout-fill md-padding>
        <div id="main-content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </md-content>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
```

Or you could use viewContentLoaded that is triggered after DOM is loaded when using uirouter in angular as below:

```
  //trigger events after DOM content load
                $scope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded",
                    function() {
                        if (document.getElementsByTagName("header").length === 2) {
                            document.getElementsByTagName("header")[1].remove();
                        }
                        if (document.getElementsByTagName("footer").length === 2) {
                            document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[1].remove();
                        }
                    });
```